# Iphone stop assetEnumerator

Tags: iphone, assets

void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL  *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

How can I stop the assetEnumerator run loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much what the documentation says:

in the block do:

```
*stop = YES;
```

Then after you current "iteration", it'll cease to enumerate the assets.